# Count from another table in FROM subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query used to select a random list of 25 sectors in a table.

```
SELECT T1.idSSecteur, T1.name_fr
FROM (

SELECT * 
FROM ssecteurs
WHERE parent =316
OR parent =317
OR parent =318
ORDER BY RAND( ) 
LIMIT 25
)T1
ORDER BY T1.name_fr
```

I have another table called `membres_ssecteurs` with the sectors associated with each member. I would like to get only sectors that have at least one member. I've tried adding a `JOIN` clause in the subquery.

```
SELECT T1.idSSecteur, T1.name_fr
FROM (

SELECT ssecteurs.idSSecteur, ssecteurs.name_fr, COUNT(membres_ssecteurs.idmembre)
FROM ssecteurs
INNER JOIN membres_ssecteurs ON ssecteurs.idSSecteur = membres_ssecteurs.idssecteur
WHERE parent =316
OR parent =317
OR parent =318
ORDER BY RAND( ) 
LIMIT 25
)T1
ORDER BY T1.name_fr
```

This query returns only one row instead of the 25 Limit.

Comment: You need a `GROUP BY` clause

Comment: As @AgRizzo has stated, use a group by clause and check when it is > 25

Comment: i don't understand why you have 2 queries in your first example. the outer query seems useless to me, as you could put everything (the columns and the order by) in the inner query.

Comment: @AgRizzo You're right, the issue was with the `GROUP BY` clause missing. I added it and was able to use `HAVING` with my memberCount. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a `GROUP BY ssecteurs.idSSecteur, ssecteurs.name_fr` and `HAVING COUNT > 0` before the ORDER BY RAND(). This will get you rows that have at least one for the COUNT:

```
SELECT T1.idSSecteur,T1.name_fr
FROM (
  SELECT ssecteurs.idSSecteur,ssecteurs.name_fr,COUNT(membres_ssecteurs.idmembre)
  FROM ssecteurs
  INNER JOIN membres_ssecteurs 
     ON ssecteurs.idSSecteur = membres_ssecteurs.idssecteur
  WHERE parent = 316 OR parent = 317 OR parent = 318
  GROUP BY ssecteurs.idSSecteur, ssecteurs.name_fr
  HAVING COUNT(membres_ssecteurs.idmembre) > 0
  ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 25
  ) T1
ORDER BY T1.name_fr
```